# Mailing list datasets

Tags: data-request, language, email

Related to this question:

- [Obtaining personal mail corpus](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4517/1511)

I'm looking for a list of archived public mailing lists from diverse communities and in diverse languages.

For example, a list would look like this:

**English**

- www.fake-link.com, Debian Linux
- www.fake-link.com, Bird Watching group

**German**

- www.fake-link.de, Fans of Berlin
- www.fake-link.de, Photography club

and so on (*und so weiter*)

One way would be to find these mailing lists, and to create a list of them, would be to use clever [google searches](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=pipermail) for things like Pipermail, and other mailing list software

```
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/chicago/
```

A great structure would be [.mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox), but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a "diverse" community, but here are some lists of mailing lists from tech communities.

- https://lists.w3.org/
- https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo
- https://commons.apache.org/mail-lists.html

Especially with the Wikimedia lists, there would be multiple written languages.